# What is the maximum battery lifetime for a sleeping microprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, batteries, microprocessor, low-power

I know it depends on the processor and the battery, I just want to know what's possible.

[EDIT:] An example would be great!

Comment: Without any further details this would just be the maximum shelf-life plus then some, probably over 20 years.

Comment: I don't see how this question is unclear. Basic, perhaps. Unclear, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sleeping microprocessor might require 30 microamps. A car battery might have a 150 amp-hour capacity. Specifics vary widely among specific models, of course. Read the datasheets.

$$ 150\:\mathrm{Ah} / 30\:\mu \mathrm A
 = 5000000\:\text{hours}
 = 208333\:\text{days}
 = 570\:\text{years} $$

This is, of course, longer than the shelf life of either product. So, provided you have room for a large battery, the current draw of the microcontroller is irrelevant. Your useful device life will be limited by other things like self-discharge of the battery, and corrosion and environmental wear on the device.

Comment: That would be much much much much longer than the self discharge time of those batteries (or any other OTS battery I know of)

Comment: @PlasmaHH yes...did you see that I say so in the answer? "Your useful device life will be limited by other things like self-discharge of the battery ..."

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to emphasize that this is much much much much longer since the typical car battery self discharges ~30% per *month* and even the best ones 2% per *month*

Answer (score 1):

A single [TL2300](http://www.tadiranbat.com/pdf.php?id=TL-2300) 3.6V cell with 100uA draw has a capacity of 13.5aH at 25°C.

[image]

So that would be about 15 years. If you reduce the current draw from 100uA you'll get reduced capacity (because some of the capacity gets used by self-discharge) but longer overall life. It's easy to make a micro draw << 100uA average, even with an RTC running and doing occasional RF transmission or whatever. Smart water meters used in our area have a "permanent" battery that is intended to outlast the life of the meter (no electrical connections at all, just a sensor and RF antenna).

Getting long battery life at high ambient temperatures is not so easy, due to the temperature relationship named after Svante Arrhenius (increased self discharge), and at low temperatures capacity decreases.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. You knew this, but I'll give you a few examples - it depends on:

1. Process/technology. HMOS/NMOS processors fare much worse; their circuits exhibit much more leakage and idle current draw than current-generation CMOS units. Many systems, like Intel's Atom series, optimize for battery usage not in just core consumption but in power states (i.e. next point).
2. Sleep state. Most microprocessors nowadays have various sleep and power states; ranging from "standby" and other idle modes to "deep sleep", where the core downclocks and peripheral units are powered down. You'd have to consult with datasheets and other information for the specific unit you have in mind.
3. What constitutes 'sleep'. Do you mean the CPU is in standby/power-down mode (that is, ready to snap back into action) or do you mean simply that the onboard RAM (in the case of microcontrollers/SoCs), caches and registers are protected and backed against failure/loss? To give you an example of historic usage, RTC modules in PC-compatibles were usually battery-backed to preserve the time in a few register sets, and even with small batteries these usually lasted decades. Standby or other low-power modes will constitute more draw. Microprocessor/controller systems particularly friendly to battery operation often provide one or more pins marked specifically for the battery supply.

It's hard to give you a concrete example because power draws, power technologies and battery capacities run the gamut from "leave it in the closet and forget about it" to "run to the other room and get the charger".

If you have a rudimentary idea of what processor you'd attempt to do this with, I could advise you better.